# How can I nest a list of items in a table where I use \multicolumn?

Tags: tables, lists, multicolumn, pandoc

I am trying to replicate the table below in LaTeX:

[image: ![A table to replicate]

At the moment, I have managed to do the following (using `\longtable` because the table is supposed to be long enough to span multiple pages):

```
\begin{longtable}{ |l|l|l| } \hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Some text \\\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{This is some text...} & Some text \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Which leads to the table as shown below:

[image: My table in LaTeX]

I am facing two issues at hand:

1. How can I add my list (1 A, 2 B, 3 C, 4...) into the cell using the `\multicolumn`?
2. Why are my vertical bars not showing completely? (These are very important.)

I should also add that I am rendering this using pandoc 2.11, if this information is significant.

Comment: welcome -- you need to share your preamble also

Comment: your lines are missing as you have `\\\\ ` so the second row only has one cell you probably want `\\&&\\ ` if you want a blank row for some reason, for the list your multicolumn is using `l` which  is like `\mbox` so can not have vertical material use `p{3cm}` or similar which is like a parbox

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That solved my problem completely. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidCarlisle's comment resolved this for me. Using `\\&\\` solved my missing vertical bars, while replacing `l` with `p{10cm}` solved my vertical material issue.

Full code here (including the preamble, my bad for not including it in the question):

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ |l|l|l| } \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Some text \\ & & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{10cm}|}{This is some text...
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item A
            \item B
            \item C
            \item D This is a long sentence. I need it to wrap around the line.
        \end{enumerate}
        There is more text here after the end of the list.
    } & Some text \\ \hline
    
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: I realize I've used `itemize` instead of `enumerate` in the image above. But for all purposes, after replacing the above, it all works as needed.